# Maintain scroll position in Kendo Grid on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a page on which I am using a Kendo Grid to populate the data. The grid has some anchor tags as the values in one of the columns.

When I click on the tag, it takes the user to a new page. There is a back button on the new page. Once this back button is clicked I need to maintain the scroll position on the main page.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
var $scrollelement = $('.k-grid-content');
if ($scrollelement.length && window.localStorage) {

  var position = localStorage.getItem('scrollelementScrollPosition');
  if (position) {
    $scrollelement.scrollTop(position);
    localStorage.setItem('scrollelementScrollPosition', 0);
  }

  $(window).on('unload', function() {
    debugger;
    var scrollPosition = $scrollelement.scrollTop();
    localStorage.setItem('scrollelementScrollPosition', scrollPosition);
  });
}
```

`LocalStorage` is working fine, but when I am setting the scroll position using `$scrollelement.scrollTop(position)`, it sets the position to a different value.

For example if the scroll position was set to `330`, it sets the scroll position to `20`, when the page is loaded. I am not sure why is the happening.

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: I am guessing that you are scrolling before the grid has finished binding the data. Try running your code inside the grid's dataBound event.

Comment: This could also help: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-scroll-selected-row

Comment: @Orilux you are right. That was the issue. thanks!